# There are random damaged (?) wrinkly spots on my sculpture. How do I fix this? (ps: it happened while I was sculpting. Smoothing didnt fix it)

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

There are random damaged (?) wrinkly spots on my sculpture's tip of nose and his bottom lip. How do I fix this? It happened while I was sculpting. No amoutn of amoothing fixed it sadly. Also any idea where I did wrong for these spots to happen? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does it give if you use the dyntopo andits option to simplify the topology, then smooth?

Comment: Thanks ı tried remesh and smoothing worked this time so problem fixed